# Send SimpleAdapter or ArrayList<Object> with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, simpleadapter

I have codes like this. This is the first class which is the source one.

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> sonucList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

HashMap<String, Object> searchHM = new HashMap<String, Object>();
searchHM.put("Name", eslenenName);
searchHM.put("image", R.drawable.appicon);
sonucList.add(searchHM);

String[] from = { "Name","image"};
int[] to = { R.id.name,R.id.imageView1};

SimpleAdapter adapterSearch = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), sonucList, R.layout.list, from, to);
```

The code is like this. I am creating a HashMap, putting some values more in  my original code. I am adding these hashmaps to ArrayList
with a for loop and creating a SimpleAdapter with this list.

What I have to do is that, send this ArrayList or SimpleAdapter to a new class. I want to create a  same listview with this adapter in another page. I tried with intent.putExtra() but putExtra doesn't accept Object it said.

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but doesn't `intent.putExtra()` require a `Serializable`? In that case, making `SimpleAdapter` `implements Serializable` might already help.

Comment: Serializable helps me when if I try to send the HashMap. But I have more than 1 HashMap so sending the HashMap is not solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler knows that `HaspMap` is `Serializable` because you're referring that `Collection` via its specific type. But it doesn't know that your `List` is `Serializable` because you're referring this `Collection` through it's specific type. There are three possibilities.

1. Use a cast, use `intent.putExtra((Serializable) sonucList);`
2. Use a specific class, declared it like this: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> sonucList = ...;`
3. Create a type parameter that implements both, `List` and `Serializable`, i.e. `<SerializableList extends List & Serializable>`, and use `SerialiableList` instead of `List`.

By the way, if you're dealing with Android, you might want to replace `Object` with `Serializable` in many places in your code to avoid `NotSerializableException` at compile time level instead of getting them at runtime.

Comment: Thank you very much. The first possibility worked. Thank you again. You saved me.

Comment: All three solutions work. I should have added that the first solution is the worst of all. Since Java 1.5, Java code should hardly ever contain casts. Although the cast seems safe, it's better to declare your `List` as `ArrayList` if possible - in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky workaround that works for all classes

Use a singleton to store the objects you want to pass

retrieve the stored objects in destination class

Comment: I never used Singleton, I don't know how it is working but I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you really want to use a singleton. http://www.riedquat.de/prog/singletonsAreEvil

Comment: formal method: use Serializable interface for the objects you want to pass